# Can I add this assumption for arbitrary family?

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

Perhaps, my question is straightforward but I want to make sure. let's consider,
$\mathcal F=\{f_{\xi}\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$   family of functions from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. If want to prove something by using the family $\mathcal F$. Can I assume each function in $\mathcal F$ repeated continuum many times even though does not state in the theorem? $\mathcal F$ just contains a continuum many times.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to prove. In the contexts I can think of it shouldn't matter whether there are repetitions or not. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you for your comment. I want there exists a function $h$ such that $h+\mathcal F\subset H$ where $H$ class of functions that stratify a specific condition. I will construct a function $h$ by transfinite induction. Does that work?

Comment: Why would it matter if $F$ contains repetitions or not in this case?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan. I want to add to get extra properties. So, I guess if I understand you correctly you can not say yes or not until see the condition. Is that right?

Comment: You say that $H$ is a class of functions; I assume you mean it's a set. That means the condition $h + F \subset H$ only depends on which functions $F$ contains, so it cannot possibly be sensitive to repetitions. It's not as if there's anything preventing you from "reusing" an element of $F$ multiple times in an argument if necessary.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I think you are answer me question. Thank you so much